# Why is xsl:when not working as expected?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am a beginner to the XSLT and I am a bit confused on how to use `xsl:when`. Please find my sample XSLT code below with expected output and the actual output I am getting from the XSLT. Could you please suggest your solution and explain what I am doing incorrect while using `xsl:when`.

**XML**

```
<source>
  <bold>Hello, world.</bold>
  <italic>fine.</italic>
  <red>I am </red>
</source>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="source">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="bold">
                    <xsl:element name="p">
                        <xsl:element name="b">
                        <xsl:value-of select="bold"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="red">
                    <xsl:element name="p">
                        <xsl:value-of select="red"></xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="italic">
                    <xsl:element name="p">
                        <xsl:element name="i">
                            <xsl:value-of select="italic"></xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="p">
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<p><b>Hello, world.</b></p>
<p><i>fine.</i></p>
<p style="color:red;">I am </p>
```

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

```
<p><b>Hello, world.</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If possible can you show how we can Implement this expected output in
>   xsl:choose?

To implement this using `xsl:choose` you could do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="source">
    <div>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="source/*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::bold">
            <p><b><xsl:apply-templates/></b></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::italic">
            <p><i><xsl:apply-templates/></i></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="self::red">
            <p style="color:red;"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that here the template using `xsl:choose` matches the actual elements children of `source` - unlike your attempt that took place at the parent `source` level.

This means that each element tests itself (hence the use of the `self` axis) and itself only. Unlike your attempt, that tested the children of `source` and returned true for the first test if **any** child of `source` was `<bold>`.

Keep in mind that just because it is possible, it doesn't mean it's the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Michael and kjhughes for encouraging beginners in great way. I think I reached the great helping platform.

Comment: hey michael, just wondering , if `<xsl:otherwise>` is compulsary in `<xsl:choose>` ? My code runs fine without it too. So just wanted to confirm from you once.

Comment: The place to confirm such things is the XSLT specification: *"The `xsl:choose `element selects one among a number of possible alternatives. It consists of a sequence of `xsl:when` elements followed by an optional `xsl:otherwise` element."* https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-choose

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Figuring out what your input XML would have been to produce the shown output given your XSLT was an unnecessary challenge, really.  Please include the input in your question next time.

**Explanation:** When your template matches the `source` element, `xsl:choose` finds only the first `xsl:when` condition whose test passes.  A better organization to achieve your desired output would break the `xsl:when` elements out into their own `xsl:templates`...

**Given this input XML:**

```
<source>
  <bold>Hello, world.</bold>
  <italic>fine.</italic>
  <red>I am </red>
</source>
```

**This XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="2.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="bold">
    <p><b><xsl:apply-templates/></b></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="red">
    <p style="color:red;"><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="italic">
    <p><i><xsl:apply-templates/></i></p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the requested output:**

```
  <p><b>Hello, world.</b></p>
  <p><i>fine.</i></p>
  <p style="color:red;">I am </p>
```

**But you really should add this additional template:**

```
  <xsl:template match="source">
    <div><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
  </xsl:template>
```

**To produce this well-formed output XML:**

```
<div>
  <p><b>Hello, world.</b></p>
  <p><i>fine.</i></p>
  <p style="color:red;">I am </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful solution and sorry I forget to add the input xml, I will include the input in future. One more thing, As per my observation, if we use xsl:choose, the expected output will not generated am I right? Only solution is to separate it with template match right. –  Nachiappan R 7 mins ago

Comment: A `xsl:choose`-based solution possible, but showing you that way would be  doing you a disservice.  With XSLT, the sooner you learn to think in terms of declarative transformations based on pattern matching rather than procedural application of tests, the more effective you'll be.

Comment: Thanks man, but I am a beginner. I will need to learn the basic things then step by step I will test the entire stuffs in XSLT. If possible can you show how we can Implement this expected output in xsl:choose?

Comment: The reason your xsl:choose doesn't work is that only the first matching xsl:when child is evaluated; the rest are ignored. It means "choose the first of the following that applies".

Comment: >If possible can you show how we can Implement this expected output in xsl:choose? No, that would be quite the wrong thing to do. You need to learn to use your new tools the way they were designed to be used, not the way that mimics tools you have used previously.